# Are Part 141 or Part 61 pilots safer?

Tags: flight-training, usa, far-61, far-141

Is there any statistical data showing whether private pilots trained at Part 61 or Part 141 schools are less likely to be involved in an accident, all else (including amount of experience, type of aircraft, etc.) being equal?

Answer (score 17):

The FAA has done this study, which can be found [here](https://rosap.ntl.bts.gov/view/dot/25747/dot_25747_DS1.pdf). The conclusion was that there is essentially no difference in accident rates between pilots trained under part 61 versus part 141.